# How can I reset Artifactory admin password in version 5.x?

Tags: artifactory

I cannot access to my Artifactory 5.x as admin user.

I was trying links from jfrog webpage: [Recreating the default admin account](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Recreating+the+Default+Admin+Account), but this procedure is valid for older versions.

Does anyone know how to reset admin password in version 5.x (5.6)?

I have access to root account on artifactory server.

**Additional question:**

In my login form there is no Password Reminder link? Why ? Artifactory OSS version...

Answer (score 3):

Passwords are now stored in the database. In my case it was mysql. Here is how I did it:

1. Connect to the database of artifactory using this command:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p artbase
   ```
2. Show the user table with this SQL sentence:

   ```
   select * from access_users;
   ```
3. Find an online bcrypt hasher and get a bcrypt hash of the password you want to set, I used [bscrypt](https://www.browserling.com/tools/bcrypt).
4. Update the admin user with this SQL sentence:

   ```
   update access_users set password='bcrypt$put_the_hash_here' where username='admin';
   ```
5. Login should work. Better change your admin password.

Comment: I'm using derby DB, not MySQL for using Artifacroy, and here's what I did to reset password: 1) Download derby from http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html , 2) `sudo java -jar /path/to/derby/derbyrun.jar ij` 3) connect `connect 'jdbc:derby:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/derby';` (path of derby may be differ) 4) update password using SQL 5) exit derby, `sudo chown -R artifactory:artifactory /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/derby`

Comment: How i generate de hash with SALT? bcript(passwd+salt)?

Comment: @VictorPinto do you mean you want to pre-choose the salt? If not, just the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

For 6 versions you can recreate users by a file called bootstrap.creds under JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/access with permission 600

> admin@*=password1

```
chmod 600 bootstrap.creds
```

And restart artifactory

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Users+and+Groups